# How do you stop conemu from inserting paragraphs into vim?

Tags: vim, conemu

I am using vim in conemu and everything goes fine until I start editing a paragraph. The second I try to add anything, everything in the above part of the paragraph gets aligned. I tried saving it and opening it up in notepad, and yes conemu is inserting paragraph breaks into it. How do I stop this???

Comment: Never seen them. And nobody was reporting about... That may be your vimrc problem.

Comment: It's not, I'm using the default vimrc.

Comment: So, what is the problem? What do you meaning?

Comment: This is a confusing question. But make absolutely sure it's not Vim's fault by starting it without any initialization files to see if the problem persists: `vim -u NONE -U NONE --noplugin -N`

Comment: ^ Wow I tried that and was really surprised it worked. Thanks and apologies for contradicting the original reply which was right. I only installed it new so it was the absolute default vimrc file.

Comment: I've created an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make absolutely sure it's not Vim's fault by starting it without any initialization files to see if the problem persists:

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE --noplugin -N
```

If that resolves your problem you can look for a `'formatoptions'` setting somewhere by doing:

```
:verbose set formatoptions?
```

Within a Vim instance started as you normally would. Note that the question mark is part of the command.

You may also want to look at the `'autoindent'` and related options, which `'formatoptions`' uses if certain formatting options are enabled.

See:

```
:help 'formatoptions'
:help fo-table
:help 'autoindent'
```